# How to check in UIButton2 method  if UIButton1 Sender is selected

Tags: iphone

I want to write code in UIButton2 method to check if UIButton1 sender is selected

```
 else if (UIButton1sender.selected == YES) {
    [UIButton2sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"52.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];
    [self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];
```

So how do i write this UIButton1sender.selected.

Thanks for help.

Comment: i am not clear about ur question.
Do u want to check the state of UIButton1 in IBAction of UIButton2?

Comment: yes. not using interface builder though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create two UIButton references in your viewController, initialize it at `viewDidLoad`, assign `IBAction`s and all the styles. Then in the button2 `IBAction` code you;ll be able to access the button1 variable like this:

```
button1->selected
```

or if you have synthesized the property for it in this way:

```
button1.isSelected
```

Keep in mind, there's yet one more property [highlighted](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/highlighted) which you might want to use instead.

Comment: it should be like this button1.isSelected or button1 isSelected ==YES

Comment: @user1452248 with the property synthesized that is either `button1.isSelected == YES` or `[button1 isSelected] == YES`

Comment: @user1452248 Not `[_rewindButton isSelected == YES]`, but `[_rewindButton isSelected]` == YES   because `[_rewindButton isSelected]` will give you the value of the property and `== YES` will give you the result of comparison with truth.

Comment: actually it should be(_rewindButton.selected == YES)

Comment: @user1452248 that is the same operation written in two ways, you'll need to read what do the properties mean and how it works.